# Function only working sometimes

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I have this function `add_log`:

```
function add_log($username, $action) {
    $l_con = new con(); 
    $log_action = $l_con->connect(); 

    // IP to put in database 
    $ip_orig = $this->getIP(); 
    $newa_ip = ip2long($ip_orig);

    $prepara = $log_action->query("INSERT INTO log VALUES ('$username',
        '$action', '$newa_ip', CURDATE(), NOW())");
}
```

When I use it in my register form it works perfectly and inserts in the database. But in the login script or anywhere else it doesn't work. I even tried putting weird names I was SURE I didn't use. I tried using it outside of the login script and still nothing.

Comment: Do you have your MySQL logging turned on? If yes please post the last entry it has. That should give a very good idea on what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are missing optional column declarations within your SQL statement. Normally you would define them as:

```
INSERT INTO table (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMNN) VALUES ('a', 'b', 'n...');
```

Also, when using `ip2long`, be aware there is an alternative where you could be doing it directly in your SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO log VALUES ('$username', '$action', INET_ATON('$new_ip'), CURDATE(), NOW())
```

To retreive, you can do `long2ip` or within your SQL, `SELECT INET_NTOA(IP) as IP ...`

Comment: field names aren't necessary in an insert, but it is good practice to specify them explicitly.

Comment: Agreed, hence the keyword normally. Is the fact they are not required not clear enough? Should i update the verbiage?

Comment: The word 'missing' made me think you meant they were required, but your answer is still good. +1 for the sql IP conversion.

Comment: I got the query to work outside of the login I added a an ID as the primary key. Is there a better method?

Comment: Auto increment your ID field if you didnt already, and you are good to go. I would suggest though, that you read up on SQL Injection and move your code to `mysqli` or `pdo` if not already.

Comment: Yeah, my code is already in PDO. Would it be safe to simply have a txt file that says username the action and date and time. Same thing but in a txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there are no quotes in $username or $action as it will break the query. Also, I'd suggest using PDO or something similar, it would make any quotes irrelevant.